# In AutoFac, what is object lifetime of ContainerScoped() when used with ASP.NET Integration?

Tags: autofac

In looking at http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration, I am confused as to what the lifetime of objects registered with `ContainerScoped()` is.

The page states:

> The ContainerDisposalModule lets Autofac dispose of any components created during request processing as soon as the request completes.

Which seems to me to indicate that `ContainerScoped()` registrations would return the same instance for every resolve during a single HttpRequest - and that no given object instance would be shared across HttpRequests.

However, if that were the case, I don't see the purpose of the `HttpRequestScoped()` method, which makes me believe that I am missing something.

What is the object lifetime of `ContainerScoped()` registrations when using `Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule` in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using an old version of Autofac? Off the top of my head the method "ContainerScoped()" is called "InstancePerLifetimeScope" in later versions and I think (not sure though) that the "HttpRequestScoped" function is deprecated. Anyhow, the two methods would be equivalent since a lifetime scope (child container) is created per request.

Comment: It looks like I am using Autofac version 1.4.3.536.

Comment: And it looks like you are correct in that "ContainerScoped()" is now called "InstancePerLifetimeScope" per http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2